# Link two places at sources in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have related Java code and PL/SQL code, at Java I'm declaring procedure something like

```
saveOperationProcedure = procedure("save_operation", getParametersForSaveOperationProcedure());
```

Since Idea doesn't know that that string literal "save_operation" refers to a PL/SQL procedure, I can't jump to declaration very easily as it would be some java method. I have to use search, bookmarks or use simple project navigation to go to that function from that place of java declaration.

Is it possible to link somehow procedure declaration at Java with actual PL/SQL source? I have already tried Javadoc @see, @link and "a" tag - don't work.

Comment: Possibly [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4486?pr=) but haven't personally used it.

Comment: Doesn't work with new versions of Idea, I have tried similar plugin (DB Navigator), as it describes, it has functionality to search database options by name, but: 1) it doesn't work for some reason by procedure name; 2) it is still manual search anyway..